# Select Grouped Column Values Where Have Same Id In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this.

TABLE-1

```
   id         Code
   -----------------
   1          N188
   1          N1Z2
   1          N222
   2          N189
   2          N1Z2
   2          N1Z3
   3          N188
   3          A123
   3          B321
   4          N188
   4          A333
   4          B444
```

I want to select id and code only code has `N188`.Result should like this:

TABLE-2

```
 id         Code
 ---------------
 1          N188
 1          N1Z2
 1          N222
 3          N188
 3          A123
 3          B321
 4          N188
 4          A333
 4          B444
```

How can I write sql for this in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT id, code
FROM table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE t.id = t2.id
        AND t2.Code = 'N188'
)
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1c21/1)

Comment: I couldt want to select 'N188' I want to select id and code where CODE have N188

Comment: @tcett -- Given your desired results, using `exists` should do just that.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, try it out -- it will produce your results from above.

Comment: Sorr for missunderstanding your code.It works thanks.But Iwan to ask WHAT does it means select 1 from in where condition?

Comment: When using `EXISTS`, you don't have to select any fields -- it's the same as saying `select id`, but slightly more performant.  Glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename A
       JOIN (SELECT id
             FROM   tablename
             WHERE  code = 'N188') B
         ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method that uses window functions:

```
select id, code
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when code = 'N188' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as cnt_n188
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt_n188 > 0;
```